# how get status of all the toggle button present in the listview android

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

how get status of all the toggle button present in the list view android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        pos = position;

        ApplicationInfo entry = ai.get(position);
        String str = insatllApps.get(position);
        System.out.println("Position============"+(insatllApps.get(position)));
        //Log.d("Check>>:","size>>"+insatllApps.size());
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list__button, null);
        t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        iv=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tb1=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.togal);
        tb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb1.setTag(pos);
        tb1.setTag(R.id.togal, str);

        iv.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));


        t1.setText(str);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.togal:

            String str = ""+v.getTag(R.id.togal);
            boolean status;

            Log.d("samit", "str>>>>"+str);

            //Integer in =  Integer.getInteger(str);
            //Log.d("samit", "in>>>>"+in);
            //int i =in.intValue();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "samit id>>"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "samit id>>"+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.d("samit", "id>>>>"+i);

            break;
        }
    }
```

here i want to get status of all the toggle button present in the listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use ArrayAdapter instead of baseAdapter by using this you can resolve the scrolling issue.
>    next in onStop() you save the values in the sharedpreference and onStart() you retrieve the values from the sharedpreference

```
public class PlanetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {  

private LayoutInflater inflater;  

public PlanetArrayAdapter( Context context, List<Planet> planetList ) {  
super( context, R.layout.checklist, R.id.textView1, planetList );  
// Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.  
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;  
}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
// Planet to display  
Planet planet = (Planet) this.getItem( position );   

// The child views in each row.  
ToggleButton checkBox ;   
TextView textView ;   

// Create a new row view  
if ( convertView == null ) {  
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checklist, null);  

  // Find the child views.  
  textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.textView1 );  
  checkBox = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById( R.id.checkBox1 );  

  // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to   
  // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.  
  convertView.setTag( new PlanetViewHolder(textView,checkBox) );  

  // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.  
  checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ToggleButton cb = (ToggleButton) v ;
        Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();  
        planet.setChecked( cb.isChecked() ); 
    }
});

}  
// Reuse existing row view  
else {  
  // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().  
  PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
  checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox() ;  
  textView = viewHolder.getTextView() ;  
}  

// Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we can  
// access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.  
checkBox.setTag( planet );   

// Display planet data  
checkBox.setChecked( planet.isChecked() );  
textView.setText( planet.getName() );        

return convertView;  
}  

 }
```

> //my activity class is....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView;
//private Planet[] planets;
ArrayList<Planet> planets=new ArrayList<Planet>();
private ArrayAdapter<Planet> listAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the ListView resource.
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and
    // Planet.

    mainListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                    planet.toggleChecked();
                    PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) item
                            .getTag();
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(planet.isChecked());
                }
            });

    // Create and populate planets.
    //planets = (ArrayList<Planet>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    planets.add(new Planet("1", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("2", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("3", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("4", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("5", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("6", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("7", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("8", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("9", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("10", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("11", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("12", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("13", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("14", false));


    // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
    listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(this, planets);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return planets;
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    for(int i=0;i<planets.size();i++){
        Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem(i);
        planet.toggleChecked();
        System.out.println("position is checked"+i+"="+planet.isChecked());

         SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);   
         SharedPreferences.Editor et=sp.edit();
         et.putString(""+i, ""+planet.isChecked());
         et.commit();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences pf=getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
    for(int i=0;i<planets.size();i++){
        Log.v("===i===",""+pf.getString(""+i,""));
        if(pf.getString(""+i,"").equals("false")){
        planets.set(i, new Planet(""+i, true));
        }
        else{

        }
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the toggle for every item in your backing array, this won't work.  The listView only keeps N rows around, where N is whatever fits onscreen.  Rows above or below don't actually exist, so you can't query the value of the toggle.  What you have to do instead is hold an array that holds the values that the toggles should be, and set those values when that position becomes visible.

For example, I see you have an array of ApplicationInfo and an array of Strings that you get for the position.  Instead, you should have 1 array of a class ListItems which holds the ApplicationInfo, name, and toggle value for each row.  When getView is called, you fill in those values to the row view.  When someone toggles the toggle, you should have an onClickListener which saves the new value back to the array of ListItems.